# Why isn't the focus attribute applied to the css of a lwc working?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

I recently noticed that adding the :focus tag to the css of a div in a lwc does not seem to be applied.  The :hover tag works just fine however so it seems to be specific to the :focus tag.

HTML

```
<div onclick={offerSelected} title={eligibleOffer.Type__c} class="focusEffect slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-grid slds-m-bottom_xx-small" key={eligibleOffer.Type__c} style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_2-of-12 slds-medium-size_3-of-12" >
                            <lightning-icon size="xx-small" icon-name="action:new" class="slds-m-left_small"></lightning-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_10-of-12 slds-medium-size_9-of-12">
                            <p class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-left_x-small slds-text-align_left" style="margin-top:2px;">
                                {eligibleOffer.Type__c}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .focusEffect:focus {
       background-color:red;
    }
```

However this works

```
    .focusEffect:hover {
       background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you use chrome inspect, and force state of focus on the div, it will change color.

[image]

On your div, there is no indication saying that the element can be focused. You have to explcitly specify that it can be.

We use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) on div to specify that it can be focussed.

> tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential
>   keyboard navigation, but its order is defined by the document's source
>   order.

```
 <div class="focusEffect slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-grid slds-m-bottom_xx-small" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_2-of-12 slds-medium-size_3-of-12" >
                            <lightning-icon size="xx-small" icon-name="action:new" class="slds-m-left_small"></lightning-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_10-of-12 slds-medium-size_9-of-12">
                            <p class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-left_x-small slds-text-align_left" style="margin-top:2px;">

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the tabindex attribute to the div to make it work

https://bitsofco.de/how-and-when-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/